# Angular side nav with 2 versions

Tags: angular

sorry for my bad english, but i've tried to use 2 sidenavs on my page, where the main content is a table of roles, whenever i click on the plus to add a role i get the sidenav form to add it, and when i try to modify a role i get the modification form.
The sidenav works perfectly when it's just one sidenav, however when i try 2 sidenavs it lays over the table and i need to push it.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" [hasBackdrop]="false">

    <mat-sidenav #sidenav1 mode="side" position="end" class="custom-drawer">
        <div class="header">
            <h4>Ajout d'un rôle 1</h4>
            <bl-button [iconClass]="'ph-x'" (click)="closeDrawer1()" [iconButton]="true"></bl-button>
        </div>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <role-add class="form"></role-add>
    </mat-sidenav>
<!--    <mat-sidenav #sidenav2 mode="side" position="end" class="custom-drawer">-->
<!--        <div class="header">-->
<!--            <h4>Modifier un role</h4>-->
<!--            <bl-button [iconClass]="'ph-x'" (click)="closeDrawer2()"[iconButton]="true"></bl-button>-->
<!--        </div>-->
<!--        <mat-divider></mat-divider>-->
<!--        <role-modif class="form"></role-modif>-->
<!--    </mat-sidenav>-->


    <mat-sidenav-content class="content">
        <bl-table [config]="config" [testLabelValue]="'table-example-1'" id="bl-example-table-sample"></bl-table>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {
  BlDataTableFilters,
  BlDialogService,
  BlTableComponent,
  BlTableConfig,
  BlTableSource,
  IconClassEnum
} from "@bl/elements";
import {MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material/table";
import {
  ACTION_COPY,
  ACTION_DELETE, ACTION_MODIFY, ACTION_TREE,
  getButtonInstance
} from "../../home/components/role/factory-button/bl-factory-action-button";
import {TranslateService} from "@ngx-translate/core";
import {MatDialog} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {DataService} from "../../../../root/services/data.service";
import {LayoutRepository} from "@bl-microfront/layout";
import {ApplicationService} from "../../../core/services/features/application.service";
import {MatDrawer, MatSidenav} from '@angular/material/sidenav';

@Component({
  selector: 'role-component',
  templateUrl: './role.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./role.component.scss']
})
export class RoleComponent implements OnInit {

    // @ViewChild('drawer1') drawer1!: MatDrawer;
    // @ViewChild('drawer2') drawer2!: MatDrawer;
  @ViewChild('sidenav1') sidenav1!: MatSidenav;
  @ViewChild('sidenav2') sidenav2!: MatSidenav;
    @ViewChild('verticalTable',{static: false}) verticalTable: BlTableComponent;
  public config: BlTableConfig;
  private datasource :MatTableDataSource<any>

  private actionDeleteColumn = getButtonInstance(ACTION_DELETE);
  private actionCopyColumn = getButtonInstance(ACTION_COPY);
  private actionModifyColumn = getButtonInstance(ACTION_MODIFY);
  private actionModifyRoleColumn = getButtonInstance(ACTION_TREE);
  private refreshEvent: EventEmitter<BlDataTableFilters>;
  private rowClickEvent: EventEmitter<any>;
  private addEvent = new EventEmitter();
  public classValidate = IconClassEnum.validate;
  chaine: any;
  public modifyValue: any;
  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService ,
              private dialog : MatDialog,
              private dataService :DataService,
              private layoutRepository:LayoutRepository,
              private applicationService:ApplicationService,
              private blDialogService: BlDialogService) {
    //this.datasource. = new MatTableDataSource<any>(ELEMENT_DATA);
    this.datasource = new MatTableDataSource<any>;
    this.initDataTable()
    this.initData(this.config,this.datasource)
    this.initConfigFirstTable();

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.datasource.data);
  }


  addUser(){

  }

  modifUser(){
    console.log("modif")
  }

  modifRole(){

  }


  initConfigFirstTable() {
    this.config = {
      globalParam: {
        right: {
          groupActionButton: true, // action button at the top of header
          expandableRows: false, // is the table having expandable rows
          filter: true, // because no exist filter
          columnAction: true, // right to have action column
          selectOne: false, //- right to select one row
          selectAll: false, //-- right to select all the row of the display page
          search: true, //-- right to have rapid search
          add: true, //-- right to add a new element with plus button
          hidePaginator: false, //-- right to activate/deactivate paginator
          hideRefresh:true
        }
      },
      columnAction: {
        width: '15%',
        list: this.getColumnAction()
      },
      data: {
        column: [
          {
            name: 'application',
            value: this.translateService.instant('sample.datatable.header.application'),
            align: 'left',
            width: '15%'
          },
          {
            name: 'role_code',
            value: this.translateService.instant('sample.datatable.header.role_code'),
            align: 'center',
            width: '15%'
          },
          {
            name: 'role_name',
            value: this.translateService.instant('sample.datatable.header.role_name'),
            align: 'center',
            width: '20%'
          },
          {
            name: 'checked',
            value: this.translateService.instant('sample.datatable.header.checked'),
            align: 'left',
            width: '20%'
          },

          {
            name: 'state',
            value: this.translateService.instant('sample.datatable.header.state'),
            align: 'left',
            width: '15%'
          },
        ],
        dataCount: 150,
        datasource: this.datasource,
        pageSizeOption: [5, 50, 100, 200],
        defaultSort: {active: 'id', direction: 'asc'}
      },

      event: {
        refresh: this.refreshEvent,
        clickRow: this.rowClickEvent,
        add: this.addEvent
      },

    };
  }

  private getGroupedActionsFirstTable() {
    return [];
  }



  private getColumnAction(){

    this.actionModifyColumn.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    this.actionModifyColumn.eventEmitter.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(value)
      this.sidenav2.toggle()
      this.applicationService.sendEvent(value);
      this.layoutRepository.openContentRightPanel();
    });

    this.actionDeleteColumn.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
    this.actionDeleteColumn.eventEmitter.subscribe(() => {
      this.openDialog()
      console.log("hello delete")
    });

    return [this.actionModifyColumn,this.actionDeleteColumn];
  }

  private initData(config: BlTableConfig, datasource: MatTableDataSource<BlTableSource>): void {
    const pageSize = this.config?.globalParam?.right?.hidePaginator ? this.config?.data?.dataCount : 50;
    const dataTableFilters: BlDataTableFilters = {
      filters: null,
      paginatorValues: {
        length: this.datasource.data.length,
        pageIndex: 0,
        pageSize: this.config?.data?.pageSizeOption?.length && this.config?.data?.pageSizeOption?.length > 0 && !this.config?.globalParam?.right?.hidePaginator ? this.config?.data?.pageSizeOption[0] : pageSize,
        previousPageIndex: 0
      },
      sortValues: null,
      search: null
    }
  }


  private initDataTable(){
    this.datasource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
    //this.datasource.data = this.dataService.initListUser();
    this.applicationService.rolesList().subscribe(data=> {
      console.log("SERVER ",data)
      this.datasource.data = data.map(item =>({
        application:item.application.applicationCode,
        role_code:item.roleCode,
        role_name:item.roleName,
        checked:item.state,
        state: item.state
      }));

    });
    this.addEvent.subscribe(()=> this.sidenav1.toggle() )
    // this.addEvent.subscribe(()=> this.layoutRepository.openRightPanel('exemple1') )
  }

  closeDrawer1(){
    this.sidenav1.toggle()
  }

  closeDrawer2(){
    this.sidenav2.toggle()
  }

  openDialog(){
    const successEvent = new EventEmitter();
    successEvent.subscribe((resp) =>
        console.log(resp)
    );
    const closeEvent = new EventEmitter();
    closeEvent.subscribe((resp) =>
        console.log(resp)
    );
    this.blDialogService.openSuccessDialog(
        {data: 'Success'},
        'sample.dialog.success.title',
        'sample.dialog.success.text',
        null,
        null,
        null,
        false);

  }




}
```

I've tried to use a drawer but i get the same behaviour

Comment: Why do you need to have two `mat-sidenav`? You can replace the content of the `mat-sidenav` itself using some sort of condition such as `*ngIf`. Having two `mat-sidenav` is not the way to go.

Comment: Yeah u are right, i think having an if condition is the way to go.
Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Please let me know if you have additional questions.